# How to save my userData when click on 'Edit' button in a table row in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a table with UserInformations and in each row I have added 'edit' and 'delete' button.
When the Edit button is on Editable mode then it changes to InputText field and I can update the names.
In Rows.jsx file I have created a function call 'onSaveStopEditing' and here I have setState the new User Data which is coming from state to variable call 'UsersData'. But now I need to send this state data as 'callBack(data)' function to parents ( which is table_view.jsx) and then update/overwrite it to the original data. 
I have tried several ways to send the data to parent via callback function but nothing seem to work for me. Also tried to check in Internet but haven't got the answer I am looking for.
Any help from you will be much Appreciated ! Thanks in Advance.

My Code link: https://codesandbox.io/s/edit-delete-inreact-dec2019-8hslp

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It looks like `this.state[name]` should be `this.state.usersData[name]` (line 26)
2. Line 50 should be removed because it's changing shape of the state.
3. What ways have you tried to pass the callback? It looks like you have

```
          {data.map(item => {
            console.log("Data-item", item);
            return <Rows item={item} />;
          })}
```

Have you tried just passing the callback as props like:

```
          {data.map(item => {
            console.log("Data-item", item);
            return <Rows callback={someFn} item={item} />;
          })}
```

And then from row:

```
props.callback(whateverDataToSend)
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response, Wil try and let you know if it works.

Comment: I did follow your instruction and now I am getting the new user data ( as JSon strings in my Alert box now the problem is how do I set them in my Table. Thanks in Advance!  Here is the code:  https://codesandbox.io/s/edit-delete-inreact-dec2019-8hslp

Comment: @Ayesha they appear to be in the table, on code sandbox, what is the issue?